# Django - argument of type 'WSGIRequest' is not iterable

Tags: django, django-forms

How do you fix the following Django bug when working with forms?

```
TypeError at /url/
argument of type 'WSGIRequest' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging my code for ~45 minutes, I found the following line needed to pass the request dictionary of posted information instead of the request itself:

```
# This: 
#    job_form = JobForm(request)
# Should Be: 
job_form = JobForm(request.GET) # OR
job_form = JobForm(request.POST)
```

Couldn't turn anything up originally on Google.  Hope this helps someone!